# How to distinctly show markers with same location?

Tags: android

I am using a cluster manager to cluster the markers on map in Android. How can I distinctly show 2 or more markers with same location? Now it is appearing as one.

Comment: This can be only done when you are plotting your marker through the database and you use the query of ditinct then plot the markers so you can only get the markers on the different location

Comment: could any one provide any code for the same :( ??